# How are the number of questions answered for the last 30 days calculated?

Tags: support, tags, top-users, tag-score

Does anyone know how Stack Exchange calculates the last 30 day answers to certain tags, like the one circled in red:

[image: Image of the statistics of a tag, with "top answerers last 30 days" highlighted]

What are the  numbers in the 1st and 2nd columns?

BTW, does below screenshot show I answered 22 questions in the [huawei-mobile-service] tag?

[image: Question showing the tag highlighted, with SO reporting 22 posts]

Comment: [Maybe it's caching](https://ShouldIBlameCaching.com/)

Comment: Hiya! Lots of stuff has helpful hover text, for example, the 22 has hover text that explains what it means. Try checking that out and see if it helps - if not, edit your question to update based on that info :)

Comment: Ah, your score for the 30 days is 0, and you have to have at least a score of 1 to appear on the leaderboard, I'll bet. :) You've certainly written several answers but they haven't been upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite often, you can hover over labels on the Stack Exchange site and a tooltip will tell you what they mean. Case in point: for the [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/huawei-mobile-services/topusers):

[image] [image]

You can also click on the '25', and it will show you [all answers by that user in that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:13329100%20%5Bhuawei-mobile-services%5D%20is:answer) (though it's not filtered on the last 30 days).

This list is sorted by total score, and as @Catija notices, you have to have a score of at least one to appear there. That's probably the cause of your confusion.

For [your own profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357441/zinna?tab=tags&sort=name):

[image]

[image]

Here, you can also click on the 3, or the tag itself, to get a [list of your posts in that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:14357441+%5Bhuawei-mobile-services%5D) - though it will contain both questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

First column is all of the answerer's total score on that tag (in last 30 days),
and the second column means the answerer's total count of the answer on that tag. (in last 30 days)

and the second question,

By the way, you can hover on that number to check the information too.
(from the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357397/how-does-sof-caculate-the-number-of-questions-answered-for-last-30-days/357399#comment1194009_357397))